# Which area is my question right for?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about the advantages/disadvantages of using Drobo or Synology with my Mac media server setup. I asked the question on SuperUser and someone closed it because it was too much of a "shopping question". Is this something that's ok to post in the Apple Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardware recommendations are off topic here. It looks to me like [your question](https://superuser.com/questions/378010/drobo-or-synology) is pretty much a hardware recommendation, so it would not be on topic here.

If you have a question about a specific piece of hardware (e.g., 'Can I use Plex to play files on my Drobo?'), you can ask it here.

See this [Stack Exchange Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for info on shopping recommendation questions, and our [FAQs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for info on what is on topic specifically on Ask Different.